# Which is more natural? ボディー vs ボディ

Tags: translation, loanwords, english-to-japanese, punctuation

**Which sentence is more natural?**

**Sentence 1**:

> また、突出部１６４は、シャフト１３０と平行にボディ１６２から延長形成されることができる。

**Sentence 2**:

> また、突出部１６４はシャフト１３０と平行にボディー１６２から延長形成されることができる。

Is ボディー a better translation for Body? Or is  ボディ better? **Which is use for a scientific setting with the lengthen vowel or without?**

Comment: Could you please ask your two questions separately?  The comma question doesn't seem like it's related to the ボディ/ボディー question.

Comment: I think the answers in this [ユーザー/ユーザ question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6-or-%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC-which-is-more-in-use-or-is-there-no-difference?rq=1) will help. Personal vote for ボディ though.

Comment: And see [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15810/5010). I think ボディ and ボディー are both safe in technical writings, because it's a short word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either ホディ or ボディー are equally common, but (I believe) the recent trend among experts is the former.

Incidentally, されることができる is wrong, it should be することができる if it's referring to capability or されることがある if it's probability.